# Download Error 404 while running torbrowser-launcher on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc not available

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, ubuntu, tor-install

I'm trying to install `Tor browser` from this [article over here](https://itsfoss.com/install-tar-browser-linux/).
I'm using methon no. 2: Install Tor browser launcher using APT (Alternate Method).

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so I've made sure the Universe repository is enabled.
`sudo add-apt-repository universe && sudo apt update`

After that, I've installed the Tor browser launcher like this:
`sudo apt install torbrowser-launcher`
It was all fine. No hurdles on the way.

I understand that this is not the browser itself. Tor browser launcher is just the installer. So, I've run the launcher using the following command:
`torbrowser-launcher`
and while this command was executed, an Error 404 was displayed. The second file was not there to be downloaded.

```
my_login@huawei-matebook-d16:~$ torbrowser-launcher
Tor Browser Launcher
By Micah Lee, licensed under MIT
version 0.3.3
https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher
Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
Downloading Tor Browser for the first time.
Downloading https://aus1.torproject.org/torbrowser/update_3/release/Linux_x86_64-gcc3/x/en-US
Latest version: 12.0.2
Downloading https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc
Download Error: 404
```

This file simply doesn't exist under the specified url address.
`https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc`

I went to this site: `https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.2/` and there is no such file there: `https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_en-US.tar.xz.asc`.
There is only this file:`https://dist.torproject.org/torbrowser/12.0.2/tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_ALL.tar.xz.asc`.

What should I do now?
Is the installer broken?
I'm reluctant to use flatpack. I already have this snaps I have to deal with and apt installer. I don't want to install software using third way of doing this. I want to use a working apt installer method.

I it possible to edit this url path somewhere, to point Tor launcher to existing `tor-browser-linux64-12.0.2_ALL.tar.xz.asc` file?

Comment: fwiw, I think the [official download](https://www.torproject.org/download/) is the easiest. You don't need to install anything, just download, decompress, and run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Ubuntu is a piece of Sh...elscripts after the version 9, and you hit it too. Use only official Tor apt repositories - and you're absolutely correct to insist on using a proper package manager such as APT. The guide - and even an Ubuntu-related warning - is on the official page https://support.torproject.org/apt/ - just follow the instructions for Debian, they will fit too - and remove the universe-installed launcher first! After that - follow the instructions to download *via tor* the Tor browser itself - they are at (https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation/)[https://tb-manual.torproject.org/installation/] and at that document you'll have a next doc linked - about updating it automatically - just do it once and it will be all set :) If you want to automate it all - use `wget` with the Tor installed from apt as a SOCKS5s proxy in a shell script

Answer (score 3):

After running:
sudo sed -i 's|self.language =.*|self.language = "ALL"|g' /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/torbrowser_launcher/common.py

- Tor-browser downloads OK (Downloading Tor Browser for the first time) but fails to install / launch -> Sorry, Ubuntu 22.04 has experienced an internal error (Installing hangs)
- Show details (Authentication required)
- Title -> torbrowser-launcher crashed with FileNotFoundError...blah blah blah...'home/username/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL/Browser/TorBrowser/Docs/Changelog.txt
- Go to your Home-folder and Show Hidden Files
- Check the folder path described for the missing file (Changelog.txt)
- THE FOLDER STRUCTURE IS WRONG! There is no "tor-browser_ALL" directory but "tor-browser" instead.
- Create the new folder 'home/username/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64/tor-browser_ALL (SHIFT+CTRL+N)
- In the directory 'home/username/.local/share/torbrowser/tbb/x86_64 you should now have two folders: The original tor-browser folder and the tor-browser_ALL folder just created
- Copy all the contents of tor-browser to tor-browser_ALL
- Re-launch the Tor browser

Comment: I confirm that these instructions correct the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The version of torbrowser-launcher in your package manager is too old. For it to work correctly, you'll need version 0.3.6. This specific bug was fixed in [#661](https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher/pull/661).